# Get specific fields from entity and a related entity with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to get all my projects (id, title, description) with their statuses (only id and title) in an optimized way.

In my repository:

```
public function getProjectsWithStatuses() {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->leftJoin('e.statuses', 'r')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

And that in my controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$projects = $em->getRepository('TutoCrmBundle:Project')->getProjectsWithStatuses();

var_dump($projects); die();
```

I got the same thing as using this directly on the controller:

```
$projects = $em->getRepository('AkimediaCrmBundle:Project')->findAll();
```

But how to create optimized query (only needed fields + earger loading) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're joining the related entity, but you're not selecting anything:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->leftJoin('e.statuses', 'r')
    ->addSelect('r')
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: And if a want to get only project title and their status titles ?
I tried that: ->addSelect('e.title', 'r.title') but I get a lot more.

Comment: You could use [Partial Objects](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html).